# Can I copy and paste node_modules, public,src ,package.json, etc in folder created by npx create-react-app to other folder?

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I am working on react application and have less Internet, Every time creating a new react-app I should do npx create-react-app which downloads about 185 MB of files.
FIles Includes node_modules,src,public etc. Can I just copy and paste these basic folders from one folder to another?
what are the circumstances if I use it?
Is there any problem that I will face in the future?

Comment: ? so what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While coping whole node_modules and then running `npm install` in the new directory should theoretically work fine (while speeding up the dependency install significantly), if you have a problem of slow internet, or low data, I’d personally recommend installing local npm proxy (registry). See eg. https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/what-is-verdaccio.html